# How to display an error message during registration for duplicate user?

Tags: django, validation

I know it's simple and I have tried searching extensively but nothing works :(

When i try this in my forms.py:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(unique = True, error_messages = {'unique':'Duplicate Error!')
    password = forms.CharField( widget = forms.PasswordInput(render_value = False), label = "Password")
```

I get an error saying:
`init() got an unexpected keyword argument: unique`

I see people getting it to work easily but clearly I am missing something.
how can I add a custom error message for user registration using the form and view code given above? I want to display the error message beside the username field just like the error message displayes when the field is left empty.

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the clean method on the form to validate this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField( widget = forms.PasswordInput(render_value = False),label = "Password")

    def clean(self):

        if User.objects.filter(email=self.cleaned_data['email']).exists():
            msg = _(u'Duplicate Error!')
            self._errors['email'] = ErrorList([msg])
            del self.cleaned_data['email']
        return self.cleaned_data
```

Comment: This will display the error on the debug page. I want the error to display under the username field instead of on the debug page.

Comment: Have you tried this code? Remove the unique = True, error_messages = {'unique':'Duplicate Error!'} from the code first...

edit: need to import User too
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

Comment: Which model do you use to save this data? The clean method is called when you do form.is_valid()

Comment: I also tried the clean function that you have given above. Still only throws IntegrityError